# How to call webhook Rest URl of localhost with Dialog Flow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to call my Rest webhook from dialog flow console.
I know it is feasible with deployment to any public ip.

But how to test the same without hosting the webhook to any public IP, and test it via localhost:8080/webhook?

Comment: you can use ngrok tool for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this - Dialogflow needs a public HTTPS server to access.

Fortunately, you can use a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which will create a tunnel between your machine and a public host name/address. You run ngrok on your localhost and tell it what local port your server is on. It will display a hostname that you can plug into Dialogflow. As long as you keep ngrok running locally, you'll have that address.

Comment: Will we able to debug in that case

Comment: It depends exactly what you mean by "debug", but yes.

Comment: Hitting the breakpoints of the application, in my case it is not

Comment: @Sana- I suggest you open a new StackOverflow question, providing as many details as possible explaining what you're trying to do (including code and the environment you're using), how you're doing it, and what isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Run your local host server as you do.

Then download the following utility.

https://ngrok.com/download

Then unzip it and you will get a ngrok binary.

Then run, 
ngrok http portnu

here port number is the one where your local webserver is listening.

On running the above command, ngrok will provide a http as well as a https public url.
Use that public url as your fulfillment logic on dialog flow console.
And now you have a local webhook running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webhook Relay (https://webhookrelay.com) to create webhook forwarding tunnels:

```
$ relay forward -b webhook-demo http://localhost:8080/webhook
Forwarding:
https://my.webhookrelay.com/v1/webhooks/5e722a5e-f3d2-4hqec-9e9f-79f1158e4b10 -> http://localhost:8080/webhook
starting webhook relay agent..
```

Endpoints are permanent (until you delete them) and it is also possible to inspect webhook body, retry them or fan-out webhooks to more than one destination.